# Encountering "10006 TXN_AUTH_REQUIRED" error in GridDB during client request execution

Tags: java, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I am currently facing an issue while executing a client request in GridDB, and I'm receiving the error code "10006 TXN_AUTH_REQUIRED." This error occurs.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I have tried setting a longer client "transaction timeout" time. For instance, I followed the example below to set the transaction timeout to 60 seconds:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("transactionTimeout", "60");
GridStoreFactory.getInstance().setProperty(prop);
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getGridStore(prop);
```